# parallel K nearest neighbor using openmp and segmentation fault

Tags: c++, visual-c++, openmp, knn

I'm trying to do k nearest neighbor (KNN) of the data points in "dat", so my first step is to construct a distance matrix between each point and all the other points, then for each point find the K nearest neighbor. The following code works perfect in serial without openmp. However, when I use openmp it gives a segmentation fault. I think this error has to do with how I update smallest which contains the index of the k smallest elements. I thought may be I need to use "reduction" with the vector smallest, but I'm not sure how to use it or is it right or wrong, so any help on how to overcome this segmentation fault is really appreciated.

```
vector<vector<double> > dist(dat.size(), vector<double>(dat.size()));
size_t p,j;
ptrdiff_t i;
vector<double> sumKnn;
vector<vector<int > > smallest(dat.size(), vector<int>(k));
#pragma omp parallel for private(p,j,i) default(shared)
for(p=0;p<dat.size();++p)
{
    int mycont=0;
    for (j = p+1; j < dat.size(); ++j)
    {
        double ecl = 0.0;
        for (i = 0; i < c; ++i)
        {
            ecl += (dat[p][i] - dat[j][i]) * (dat[p][i] - dat[j][i]);
        }
        ecl = sqrt(ecl);
        dist[p][j] = ecl;
        dist[j][p] = ecl;
        int index=0; 
        if(mycont<k && j!=p)
        {
            smallest[p][j-p-1]=j;
            mycont++;
        }
        else
        {
            double max=0.0;
            int index=0;
            for(int i=0;i<smallest[p].size();i++)
            {
                if(max < dist[p][smallest[p][i]])
                {
                    index=i;
                    max=dist[p][smallest[p][i]];
                } 
            }
            if(max>dist[p][j])
            {
                smallest[p].erase(smallest[p].begin()+index);
                smallest[p].push_back(j);
            }
        }        
    }
double sum=0.0;
for(int r=0;r<k;r++)
    sum+= dist[p][smallest[p][r]];
sumKnn.push_back(sum);
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between a "k nearest neighbor KNN" and ordinary KNN?

Comment: it's the same just I want to make it parrallel

Comment: Have you considered using kd-tree instead of parellizing the algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use "critical" directive:

```
#pragma omp critical
{
smallest[p].erase(smallest[p].begin()+index);
smallest[p].push_back(j); 
}
```

and

```
#pragma omp critical
sumKnn.push_back(sum);
```

But I agree, that better is to use kd-tree or k-means tree istead of parallelization. You can just download FLANN library http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~mariusm/index.php/FLANN/FLANN.

Answer (score 0):

So I agree with @izomorphius that parallelizing this algorithm (where all distances are calculated) is probably not going to be a speedup compared to using a faster tree-based algorithm, particularly for very large numbers of points.

Still, you can do this fairly easily.  The problem is you can't be have multiple threads doing things like push_back() and erase() on shared vectors at the same time.   And frankly vectors look like the wrong approaches to be using for these things anyway; since you know the sizes of these things, just using arrays is probably the way to go.

At any rate, by manually moving things around in the smallest[][] array instead of using erase and push back, and by just writing into a static array for sumKnn instead of using push_back(), this can be made to work.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    const int size = 25;  // number of pts
    const int k = 2;      // number of neighbours
    const int c = 2;      // number of dimensions

    vector<vector<double> > dat(size, vector<double>(c));
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        vector<double> pt(c);
        for (int d=0; d<c; d++) {
            pt.push_back(rand()*1./RAND_MAX);
        }
        dat.push_back(pt);
    }

    vector<vector<double> > dist(size, vector<double>(size));
    double sumKnn[size];

    vector<vector<int > > smallest(size, vector<int>(k));
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(dat, dist, smallest, sumKnn)
    for(size_t p=0;p<size;++p)
    {
        int mycont=0;
        for (size_t j = p+1; j < size; ++j)
        {
            double ecl = 0.0;
            for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < c; ++i)
            {
                ecl += (dat[p][i] - dat[j][i]) * (dat[p][i] - dat[j][i]);
            }
            ecl = sqrt(ecl);
            dist[p][j] = ecl;
            dist[j][p] = ecl;
            int index=0;
            if(mycont<k && j!=p)
            {
                smallest[p][j-p-1]=j;
                mycont++;
            }
            else
            {
                double max=0.0;
                int index=0;
                for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
                {
                    if(max < dist[p][smallest[p][i]])
                    {
                        index=i;
                        max=dist[p][smallest[p][i]];
                    }
                }
                if(max>dist[p][j])
                {
                    for (int ii=index; ii<k-1; ii++)
                        smallest[p][ii] = smallest[p][ii+1];
                    smallest[p][k-1] = j;
                }
            }
        }
        double sum=0.0;
        for(int r=0;r<k;r++)
            sum+= dist[p][smallest[p][r]];
        sumKnn[p] = sum;
    }


    return 0;
}
```